# SwiperJS not sliding slides with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm having problems, crating a slider which slides in react.

[image]

I importted swiper and installed ist via terminal with `npm install swiper`.

MY Swiper looks like this in the HTML:

[image]

And this is the frontEnd:

[image]

Th slider gets shown, but i cannot slide it, even when i'm adding the navigation and click it, the slides don't change.

Does anyone know this problem, or is it just a misconfiguration (hopefully)?

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you solve your problem.
https://swiperjs.com/demos

Select "React" on the wanted Swiper Demo, and then CodeBox opens. This demo might help you; 
[Demo Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/znqout?file=/src/App.jsx)

Comment: Links may change. Provide an answer or instructions on how to fix.